# Imagemagick performance

Tags: arm, imagemagick

I'm developing a small proof of concept in a small ARM SoC using Imagemagick as UI/OSD builder. While trying to improve the fancyness of the UI by using transparent gradients I found a strage performance problem with Imagemagick.

Files:

- background_with_alpha_gradient.png is https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWEu5.png.
  [image: Background with alpha gradient]
- icon.bmp is a random small image (105x170) with no alpha (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrGtE.png)
  [image: No alpha]

The idea is to use the background_with_alpha_gradient.png file as, well, background and then draw over this icon and some text.

```
$time convert /tmp/background_with_alpha_gradient.png /tmp/icon.bmp -compose Atop -composite  /tmp/foo.png 
real    0m0.520s
user    0m0.480s
sys     0m0.030s
```

Pretty fast. The problem happens when I try change the position of the icon:

```
$time convert prototype_client/assets/base_transp_workaround.png /tmp/icon.bmp -geometry +49+22  -compose Atop -composite /tmp/foo.png 
real    0m5.685s
user    0m5.530s
sys     0m0.080s
```

I'm also quite intrigued by why composing with Copy is so much slower than using Atop:

```
time convert prototype_client/assets/base_transp_workaround.png /tmp/icon.bmp  -compose Copy -composite  foo.png 
real    0m5.379s
user    0m5.310s
sys     0m0.050s
```

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you use perf to figure out? https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: The convert utility also provides [-bench](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#bench) & [-debug](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#debug) operators to help isolated performance behavior.

Comment: Are you actually using `BMP` files for the icon (you seem to swap between `BMP` and `PNG` - it actually lends itself to `PNG` format and ImageMagick loathes `BMP`s... both work in milliseconds on my machine. Are you using an old IM version? `identify -version`